# как создать чат с помощью именованного потока?

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, unix

Пытаюсь создать чат между двумя программами с помощью именованного потока, но когда запускаю программу ничего не получается, она общается будто бы сама с собой, но никак не с другой программой, при одновременном запуске с двух терпиналов вторая программа сразу же начинает считывать сообщение, при том, что оно ещё даже не было отправлено.

prog1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void read_fifo(int descriptor)
{
        char message[100]="";
        if(read(descriptor, message, sizeof(message))<0)
                perror("read");
        printf("Noname2:  %s\n", message);
}
int main(int argc, int* argv[])
{

        if(mkfifo("fifo",0666) < 0)
                perror("mkfifo");
        func();

        /*for(;;){
        int descriptor = open("fifo", O_WRONLY);
        if(descriptor<0)
                perror("open");
        write_fifo(descriptor);
        if(close(descriptor)<0)
                perror("close");

        descriptor = open("fifo", O_RDONLY);
        if(descriptor < 0)
                perror("open");
        read_fifo(descriptor);
        if(close(descriptor)<0)
                perror("close");
        }*/
        return 0;
}


void write_fifo(int descriptor)
{
        char message[100];
        fgets(message, 100, stdin);

        if(write(descriptor, message, strlen(message)+1)<0)
                perror("write");
}

void func()
{
        for(;;){
        int descriptor = open("fifo", O_WRONLY);
        if(descriptor<0)
                perror("open");
        write_fifo(descriptor);
        if(close(descriptor)<0)
                perror("close");

        descriptor = open("fifo", O_RDONLY);

        if(descriptor < 0)
                perror("open");
        read_fifo(descriptor);
        if(close(descriptor)<0)
                perror("close");
        }

}
```

prog 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

void write_fifo(int descriptor)
{
        char message[100];
        fgets(message, 100, stdin);
        if(write(descriptor, message, strlen(message)+1)<0)
                perror("write");
}

void read_fifo(int descriptor)
{
        char message[100]="";
        if(read(descriptor, message, sizeof(message))<0)
                perror("read");
        printf("Noname1:: %s\n", message);
}

void func()
{
        for(;;){
                int descriptor = open("fifo", O_RDONLY);
                if(descriptor < 0)
                perror("open");
        read_fifo(descriptor);
        if(close(descriptor)<0)
                perror("close");
        descriptor = open("fifo", O_WRONLY);
        if(descriptor<0)
                perror("open");
        write_fifo(descriptor);
        if(close(descriptor)<0)
                perror("close");
        }

}

int main(void)
{
        if(mkfifo("fifo", 0666)<0)
                perror("mkfifo");

        func();
        /*for(;;){
                int descriptor = open("fifo", O_RDONLY);
                if(descriptor < 0)
                perror("open");
        read_fifo(descriptor);
        if(close(descriptor)<0)
                perror("close");
        descriptor = open("fifo", O_WRONLY);
        if(descriptor<0)
                perror("open");
        write_fifo(descriptor);
        if(close(descriptor)<0)
                perror("close");
        }*/
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не стал подробно изучать весь текст Вашей программы, но две **принципиальные** ошибки обнаружил. Сдаётся мне, что Вы плохо представляете механизм FIFO, а ведь они мало чем отличаются от обычных файлов.

Первая ошибка. Если Вы пишите программу, которая собирается **читать** из файла, разве Вы будете **создавать** этот файл? Ведь только что созданный файл пуст - читать из него нечего... Поэтому, в реальности надо создавать FIFO не в программах, а с консоли, командой:

```
MKFIFO(1)                                               User Commands                                              MKFIFO(1)

NAME
       mkfifo - make FIFOs (named pipes)

SYNOPSIS
       mkfifo [OPTION]... NAME...

DESCRIPTION
       Create named pipes (FIFOs) with the given NAMEs.
```

А Ваши программы будут только **открывать** уже существующий FIFO. Т.е. в консоли Вы пишите нечто вроде:

```
# Создаём FIFO
mkfifo -m 0664 my_fifo

# Первым запускаем потребителя - он ждёт записи в FIFO
./consumer &

# Запускаем производителя
./produser
```

Для того, что бы две (или более) программ могли **обмениваться** сообщениями, я бы рекомендовал создать два FIFO:

```
prog1 -> FIFO-1 -> prog2
prog1 <- FIFO-2 <- prog2
```

В таком варианте логика взаимодействия (интерфейс) двух программ становятся очевидными. Надо быть внимательным с **порядком** открытия двух FIFO - что бы процессы не заблокировали друг друга. Можно сделать через один FIFO, но это гораздо сложнее.

Вторая ошибка. Это что должно значить:

```
for(;;){
                int descriptor = open("fifo", O_RDONLY);
```

?!

FIFO - самый обычный фал. Ну, почти. :-) И если некая программа собирается читать файл, то она должна открыть этот файл **один** раз - в начале своей работы и закрыть его тоже один раз - в самом конце.

Ну и совет - не надо обязательно использовать *read()/write()* при работе с FIFO. Ведь это накладывает требование **заранее знать** размер передаваемого блока. Что в FIFO записал писатель, то и должен прочитать читатель.  А на практике это довольно трудно реализовать.

Гораздо проще использовать *fgets()/fputs()*. Тогда сообщение будет представлять из себя строку **произвольной** длины.